# Not able to close jQuery UI dialog when opened from a catch block

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, catch-block

I have built a common error dialog function to get a common look and feel for my dialogs.  I call that function from within the `$.ajaxSetup.error` function without issue.  I have one button added through the call on the dialog.  My button will close the dialog and the X in the corner will close the window when called from the `ajaxSetup.error` function.

If I attempt to call this same function from within a catch block within my JS (NOT AN AJAX CALL) the dialog opens without issue but when I click my button to close the dialog I get the following error:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '_focusTabbable' of undefined or null reference

Here is the code that generates my dialog:

```
function __renderDialogOK(data) {

    // This call renders the div to be displayed within
    // the dialog.
    var divMessage = __renderDialogBase(data);

    $(divMessage).dialog(
        {
            width: __getDialogWidth(),
            resizeable: false,
            modal: true,
            hide: true,
            show: true,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "OK",
                    click: function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            ],
            open: function (e) {
                $(this).parent().find("button:eq(1)").addClass('ui-state-default');
                $(this).parent().find("button:eq(1)").focus();
                $(this).on("keydown", function (event) {
                    if (parseInt(event.keyCode) === 13) {
                        $(this).parent()
                            .find("button:eq(1)").trigger("click");
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
                        $(this).parent()
                            .find("button:eq(1)").trigger("click");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            },
            close: function (e) {
                $(this).off("keydown");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

As you can see in my button I attempt to close the dialog using `$(this)`.  I have also tried using a variable outside of the function (global) to store the context returned by the call to `$(divMessage).dialog(`.

This appears to only be happening within IE11 which is unfortunate for me since my customer has that as their current corporate standard.  So finally my question(s).

Is all context lost when you enter a Catch block within JavaScript?  Has this issue been exposed previously and I am just not seeing the threads?  I have read many of the other threads regarding this similar error message but they don't seem to be as specific as my instance and many of them seem to be because the dialog is not initiated yet.  Mine is.  The dialog is on the screen.  I just can't close it with my button.

Comment: focus is throwing the error ** $(this).parent().find("button:eq(1)").focus(); ** 
 $(this).off("keydown");

Comment: First off @Nisse thank you for your help.  It is greatly appreciated.  I took both lines out and still get the same error.  I was not sure why you mentioned the disabling of the keydown event for focus.  Does the disabling of an event cause the browser to re-focus?  Any further assistance would be very much appreciated as I am stumped.

Comment: @Krishjs my appologies I saw the edited by and thought Nisse had posted the comment.  Thank you for the help.   :-)   Sorry for the slight.

Comment: You may want to pass `$(this)` to a variable to avoid confusion between functions. Example: `var $me = $(this); var $parent = $(this).parent();` and then use $me and $parent throughout the rest of the code block for `open`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, I would examine this:

```
        open: function (e) {
            $(this).parent().find("button:eq(1)").addClass('ui-state-default');
            $(this).parent().find("button:eq(1)").focus();
            $(this).on("keydown", function (event) {
                if (parseInt(event.keyCode) === 13) {
                    $(this).parent()
                        .find("button:eq(1)").trigger("click");
                    return false;
                }

                if (event.keyCode == 27) {
                    $(this).parent()
                        .find("button:eq(1)").trigger("click");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

> In most cases, the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called. ES5 introduced the `bind` method to set the value of a function's `this` regardless of how it's called, and ES2015 introduced `arrow` functions which do provide their own `this` binding (it remains the this value of the enclosing lexical context).

So, in the `open` callback, `$(this)` refers to the object that called `open`. It is sort of similar to `$(e.target)`. So when we then bind a function via `.on()` to the `keydown` event, `$(this)` is no longer the `open` callback. It is a reference to the `keydown` callback.

To avoid confusion you can do different things. Here is what I would try first:

```
        open: function (e) {
            var $me = $(this);
            var $parent = $(this).parent();
            $parent.find("button:eq(1)").addClass('ui-state-default');
            $parent.find("button:eq(1)").focus();
            $me.on("keydown", function (event) {
                if (parseInt(event.keyCode) === 13) {
                    $parent
                        .find("button:eq(1)").trigger("click");
                    return false;
                }

                if (event.keyCode == 27) {
                    $parent
                        .find("button:eq(1)").trigger("click");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

This will help retain the proper reference to the proper objects.

Comment: Twisty, thanks for the help.  It is appreciated.  I had tried creating variables to hold my references and setting them in the open.  I tried it again like you suggested above.  The first pass used the code you put above but the problem was that the variables $me and $parent were not in scope from any of the button events.  Next I moved those two variables outside of the open event and made them class level variables ( this is what I had tried previously ) but still have the same issues.  I feel like this should all work and I must be doing something stupid but just cant figure it out.

Comment: We'll figure it out. Need to make a fiddle I think.

Comment: Thanks Twisty.  I am sorry I went so quiet.  I have been stuck in level 1 and 2 severity issues that have kind of put this one on the back burner.  I am sorry I have not put more into this issue.  I will eventually make it back to it.  Thank you for your help.